# URL rewrite for specific condition using QUERY_STRING in ASP.NET

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a rule to route the website to specific URL based on certain condition.

For example, my web site is `http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/123`. What I want is if I type `http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/999` then it should route to `https://www.sportStore.com/items/`. How to do that? I tried following which did not work.

Code:

```
<rule name="Site Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="site/department/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sportStore.com/items/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="((123)|(456)|(789)|(111)|(222)|(333))" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
</rule>
```

Actual Results:

```
http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/123 -> https://www.sportStore.com/items/
http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/456 -> https://www.sportStore.com/items/
http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/999 -> https://www.sportStore.com/items/
```

Expected Results:

```
http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/123 -> http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/123
http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/456 -> http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/456
http://www.sportStore.com/site/department/999 -> https://www.sportStore.com/items/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule for only permanently redirecting 999 department. You can obviousily add other department ids in the match url pattern:

```
<rule name="Site Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="site/department/((999))" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sportStore.com/items/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />

</rule>
```